# one-to-many merge in SAS (with mismatching records)

Tags: merge, sas

I'm trying to do a merge in SAS which seems like it should be easy, but thus far haven't found anything that points to how to do it. I have two datasets - let's call them Monthly1 and Quarterly2. Monthly1 is the main one, and I want to merge Quarterly2 onto it. The problem is, the latter has a different periodicity, as the name implies. Here is what each looks like:

MONTHLY1:

```
id,month,year,qname,data1,data2,data3,data4

1111,01,2018,First Quarter 2018,27,33,55
1111,02,2018,First Quarter 2018,28,34,54
1111,03,2018,First Quarter 2018,28,37,51
1111,04,2018,Second Quarter 2018,28,30,59
1112,01,2018,First Quarter 2018,1,7,12
1112,02,2018,First Quarter 2018,2,7,10
1112,03,2018,First Quarter 2018,5,6,7
1112,04,2018,Second Quarter 2018,4,1,8
```

QUARTERLY2:

```
id,qname,data4,data5

1111,First Quarter 2018,53,7
1111,Second Quarter 2018,58,9
1112,First Quarter 2018,7,7
1112,Second Quarter 2018,7,9
```

Merging on `id` and `qname`. So for each `month` in MONTHLY1, `data 4` is overwritten using the value in QUARTERLY2, and `data 5` is added as a new variable. The final dataset should look like (I've added a `*` where data from QUARTERLY2 is either added or overwritten):

MERGED3:

```
id,month,year,qname,data1,data2,data3,data4,data5

1111,01,2018,First Quarter 2018,27,33,53*,7*
1111,02,2018,First Quarter 2018,28,34,53*,7*
1111,03,2018,First Quarter 2018,28,37,53*,7*
1111,04,2018,Second Quarter 2018,28,30,58*,9*
1112,01,2018,First Quarter 2018,1,7,7*,7*
1112,02,2018,First Quarter 2018,2,7,7*,7*
1112,03,2018,First Quarter 2018,5,6,7*,7*
1112,04,2018,Second Quarter 2018,4,1,7*,9*
```

Thanks!

Comment: So what have you tried ?  What error messages or unexpected results are you observing ?

Comment: Sounds like you want to drop the DATA4 variable from the MONTHLY1 dataset. Did you try that?

Answer (score 2):

[Usage Note 48705](http://support.sas.com/kb/48/705.html): A one-to-many merge with common variables that are not the BY variables will have values from the many data set after the first observation, states:

> In a one-to-many merge with common variables that are not the BY
>   variables, customers sometimes expect that the value for the common
>   variable from the "one" data set will be retained throughout the BY
>   group if the "one" variable is listed second in the MERGE statement.
>   It is correct that in a one-to-one merge, and for the first matching
>   observation in a one-to-many merge, the value of a common variable in
>   the latter data set(s) overwrites the value from the previous data
>   set. However, on subsequent iterations of the MERGE statement for the
>   same BY group, the "one" data set is not read again. Therefore, the
>   resulting output contains the value of the variable from the "many"
>   data set.

You can change the behavior by renaming a non-by variable so it is not in common -- the new non-common variable value will be maintain across the subsequent many by matches and can be applied.

For example (your data)

Monthly (the many)

```
data have_monthly;
infile cards dlm=',';
length id month year 8 qname $30; input
id month year qname data1 data2 data3; data4=_n_*1000; datalines;
1111,01,2018,First Quarter 2018,27,33,55
1111,02,2018,First Quarter 2018,28,34,54
1111,03,2018,First Quarter 2018,28,37,51
1111,04,2018,Second Quarter 2018,28,30,59
1112,01,2018,First Quarter 2018,1,7,12
1112,02,2018,First Quarter 2018,2,7,10
1112,03,2018,First Quarter 2018,5,6,7
1112,04,2018,Second Quarter 2018,4,1,8
run;
```

Quarterly (the one)

```
data have_quarterly;
infile cards dlm=',';
length id 8 qname $30;
input id qname data4 data5; datalines;
1111,First Quarter 2018,53,7
1111,Second Quarter 2018,58,9
1112,First Quarter 2018,7,7
1112,Second Quarter 2018,7,9
run;
```

Default merge

```
data try (label="The quarter data4 values are not propagated");
  merge
    have_monthly
    have_quarterly
  ;
  by
    id
    qname
  ;
run;
```

Same merge with a rename to ensure non-commonality in non-by variable *data4*

```
data want(label="The quarter data4 values are propagated");
  merge
    have_monthly
    have_quarterly (rename=data4=_data4)
  ;
  by
    id
    qname
  ;
  data4 = _data4;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

Because SAS will overwrite with same named columns in a `merge` but only for first matches, consider renaming during the merge. Then, keep the columns you need. Also below demonstrates a left join merge (keeps all rows in *Montlhy1* regardless if it matches or not with *Quarterly1*):

```
proc sort data=Monthly1; by id qname; run;
proc sort data=Quarterly2; by id qname; run;

data merged3;
    merge Monthly1(in=x RENAME=(data4=data4_x)) Quarterly2(in=y);
    by id qname;
    if x;
    keep id month year qname data1-data5; 
run;
```

Alternatively, consider a left join merge with proc sql and explicitly keep the columns you intend designated by table aliases. Again, `left join` is used:

```
proc sql;
    create table merged4 as
    select m.id, m.month, m.year, m.qname, m.data1, m.data2, m.data3, q.data4, q.data5
    from Monthly1 m
    left join Quarterly2 q
      on m.id = q.id AND m.qname = q.qname;
quit;
```